# Flask-Session dosen't create session table if session interface is SQLAlchemySessionInterface

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm try to build simple flask app. I wish store server's session in database

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_session import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask( __name__ )
app.config[ 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' ] = 'sqlite://'
app.config[ 'SESSION_TYPE' ] = 'sqlalchemy'

db = SQLAlchemy( app )

Session( app )
Migrate( app, db )

manager = Manager( app )
manager.add_command( 'db', MigrateCommand )


class User( db.Model ):
    id = db.Column( db.Integer, primary_key=True )
    name = db.Column( db.String( 50 ) )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

when i use flask cli for db init, session's table not created:

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
```

part of migrate-file:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('user',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=50), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

table 'session' is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem myself. It's resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45887266/flask-session-how-to-create-the-session-table).

You can create the session table with the following line:

```
session.app.session_interface.db.create_all()
```