# flask-session: how to create the session table

Tags: python, sqlite, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to enable server-side sessions for my flask application using a SQLite database. Note I'm using [Flask-Sessionstore](https://github.com/mcrowson/flask-sessionstore) which is a hard fork of [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) and is more actively maintained. However, I'm getting the same error when I use both libraries. Here is my code for `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_sessionstore import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/Johnny/DBs/test.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False  # quiet warning message
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'sqlalchemy'
Session(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run the application with `python app.py` everything starts and runs as expected. However, when I try to access the index page at http://127.0.0.1:5000 I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: sessions [SQL: 'SELECT sessions.id AS sessions_id, sessions.session_id AS sessions_session_id, sessions.data AS sessions_data, sessions.expiry AS sessions_expiry \nFROM sessions \nWHERE sessions.session_id = ?\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'] [parameters: ('session:xxx...', 1, 0)]
```

It appears I need to create this table before running the application. How can I do this? Or am I missing a configuration option that creates the table for me if it's not found?

Comment: In case you stumble on this question in 2019: The linked github site of Flask-Session says it is not longer maintained.

Comment: Update for July 2020. https://flasksession.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ seems to be current again  and this github repo was recently updated  https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to provide this in your app config as well:

```
app.config[SESSION_SQLALCHEMY_TABLE] = 'sessions'
app.config[SESSION_SQLALCHEMY] = db
```

where `db` is sqlAlchemy instance. So you should have something like:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
session = Session(app)
session.app.session_interface.db.create_all()
```

You can take a look at the test example of [flask_sessionstore  on github](https://github.com/mcrowson/flask-sessionstore/blob/master/test_session.py)

Comment: I don't need the two config lines because they are already the defaults. However, that last line `session.app.session_interface.db.create_all()` is exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Mekicha works but if you already have your database and don't want to run `db.create_all()`, consider this alternative:

After you initialize your session instance with the app, you can use the sqlalchemy interface to build your 'session' table, if none is existent:

```
SqlAlchemySessionInterface(app, db, "sessions", "sess_")
```

Then run a migration against your database.

See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829872/1145905) for a full example

Comment: yes, if you are using alembic directly to play migrations. Adding this line to alembic/env.py permit to register Session table in db.metadata before auto-generating migrations

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, you should use the following:

```
# assuming you have already have a Flask instance, an SQLAlchemy instance, and a Session instance:
app.session_interface.sql_session_model.__table__.create(bind = db.session.bind)
```

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: @anonymous `app.session_interface.sql_session_model` is set by `flask-session` [in the source code](https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/blob/9f591b5c7ecf25c44678c7d18d94a0bf91132e2d/flask_session/sessions.py#L514), and `Model.__table__.create` is referenced [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34240889) ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.create)). Was also tested on my own Flask project.